# Nokogiri::XML doesn't removes node

Tags: ruby, xml

Actually i have that file:

```
<info version="5.0" xml:id="info-Documentation-Test09-Test09" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title>Test09</title>
        <subtitle>Enter a short description here.</subtitle>
        <productname>Documentation</productname>
        <productnumber>0.1</productnumber>
        <edition>0</edition>
        <abstract>
                <para>
                        A short overview and summary of the book's subject and purpose, traditionally no more than one paragraph long. Note: the abstract will appear in the front matter of your book and will also be placed in the description field of the book's RPM spec file.
                </para>
        </abstract>
        <orgname>
        <inlinemediaobject>
                <imageobject>
                        <imagedata fileref="Common_Content/images/title_logo.svg" format="SVG" />
                </imageobject>
        </inlinemediaobject>
        </orgname>
        <xi:include href="Common_Content/Legal_Notice.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" />
        <xi:include href="Author_Group.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" />
</info>
```

Now i would like to remove the node  with it's childs. I have tried out:

```
def self.remove_orgname(artinfo)
    # Entferne $titelbild des Artikels
    puts 'Entferne Logo aus dem Article_Info File. Wird anders gesetzt.'
    io = File.open("#{artinfo}")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(io)
    doc.search('//orgname').each do |node|
      node.delete
      node.content = 'Children removed'
    end
    io.close
  end
```

I'm running the method with giving the File "artinfo = "#{titel}/de-DE/Article_Info.xml". After running the program i can see no errors given from ruby. But it looks like Nokogiri hasn't removed that content. 
Any ideas?

Tried out also:

```
def self.remove_orgname(artinfo)
    # Entferne $titelbild des Artikels
    puts 'Entferne Logo aus dem Article_Info File. Wird anders gesetzt.'
    io = File.open("#{artinfo}")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(io)
    doc.search('//orgname').each do |node|
      node.delete
      node.content = 'Children removed'
    end
    File.open("#{artinfo}", 'w')
    io.close
  end
```

But this produces an empty file...

This one doesn't produce a empty file but it looks like it doesn't made a change:

```
def self.remove_orgname(artinfo)
    # Entferne $titelbild des Artikels
    puts 'Entferne Logo aus dem Article_Info File. Wird anders gesetzt.'
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(artinfo))
    doc.search('//orgname').each do |node|
      node.delete
      node.content = 'Children removed'
    end
    IO.write(artinfo, doc.to_xml)
  end
```

Now i have the solution:

```
def self.remove_orgname(artinfo)
    # Entferne $titelbild des Artikels
    puts 'Entferne Logo aus dem Article_Info File. Wird anders gesetzt.'
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(artinfo))
    doc.search('orgname').each do |node|
      node.remove 
      node.content = 'Children removed'
    end
    IO.write(artinfo, doc.to_xml)
  end
```

So it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loaded the file into a Nokogiri document, changed the nokogiri document, didn't save it back to the file and didn't return it out of the function. It's like loading a text in Word, changing it, then powering off your computer - you did change things, but without saving it was in vain.

EDIT: Try this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(filename))
...
IO.write(filename, doc.to_xml)
```

Comment: Hmm if i'm trying it so i get an empty file:
def self.remove_orgname(artinfo)
    # Entferne $titelbild des Artikels
    puts 'Entferne Logo aus dem Article_Info File. Wird anders gesetzt.'
    io = File.open("#{artinfo}")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(io)
    doc.search('//orgname').each do |node|
      node.delete
      node.content = 'Children removed'
    end
    File.open("#{artinfo}", 'w')
    io.close
  end

Comment: Hi Amadan. Sadly it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

That was the solution:

```
def self.remove_orgname(artinfo)
    # Entferne $titelbild des Artikels
    puts 'Entferne Logo aus dem Article_Info File. Wird anders gesetzt.'
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(artinfo))
    doc.search('orgname').each do |node|
      node.remove 
      node.content = 'Children removed'
    end
    IO.write(artinfo, doc.to_xml)
  end
```